# Erro de rota ao acessar a página no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-rotas

Galera depois que executei esse comando em meu laravel a situação em algumas páginas ficou ruim, não estão mais funcionando, o comando é o seguinte:

> composer require mnabialek/laravel-eloquent-filter

Aparece o erro abaixo, não fiz nenhuma alteração alem de executar esse comando.
***ReflectionException in Route.php line 333:
Method App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController::detalhes() does not exist***

Após isso tentei fazer o composer install e o composer update mas nada deu certo.

Abaixo o código do meu controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests\AnunciosRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Anuncio;


class AnuncioController extends Controller {

    public function detalhes($id) {
        $animal = Anuncio::find($id);

        return view('anuncio.detalhes')->with('detalhe', $animal);
    }
```

Meu arquivo de routes.php esta correto, sem alterações, a primeira página funciona, mas não sei o que ocorreu;

```
/* Rota para listar os produtos cadastrados */
Route::get("/", "HomeController@index");
Route::get("/anuncios/detalhes/{id}", "AnuncioController@detalhes");
```

Comment: Tentou usando: `Route::get('anuncios/detalhes/{id}',['as'=>'anuncios.detalhes', 'uses'=>'AnuncioController@detalhes']);` ?

Comment: Tentei agora, mas sem sucesso, mesmo erro, talvez tentar recriar tudo de novo o controller inteiro mas acho esquisito porque a página de listas acessa o mesmo controller e não retorna nenhum erro.

Comment: Isso direto acontece comigo também kk no meu caso quando crio grupo de rota ou então faço assim funciona.

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste aqui kkkk, tenso criei do zero e a mesma função chamei nesse novo controller e agora funcionou normal, estranho de mais.

Comment: kkk Laravel tem essas coisas mesmos kk por isso não gosto de usar frameworks fullstacks, sempre opto por usar o Silex ou Troubadour (um que fiz rs.. posta a resposta aí para sua própria perguta, só pra deixar registrado uma solução)

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este caso foi necessário criar novamente o controller que estava sendo utilizado anteriormente.

executado o seguinte comando:

```
php artisan make:controller AnunciarController
```

Após copiar a função para este novo controller e alterar o nome do mesmo na rota de detalhes, o erro não foi mais apresentado.